# Error while deploying report from VS

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I tried to deploy report from VS2012 to remote server, and when deploy I got error:

```
"The permissions granted to user 'SERVER\User2' are insufficient for performing this operation."
```

Deploy work excellent from other developer machine.

Problem is obviously that `User2` doesn't have enough permission.

When deploy report from VS, I usually got popup window where I specified username and password. In this case, I don't have any popup to define user for deploy.

Instead of `User2` there must be `User` but I don't know how to change them, it looks like user is preserved somewhere, I don't get popup for credentials.

`User` and `User2` both exists on remote server as account, but `User` has administrator privilege, and this is first account

Comment: Check the Windows Credentials Vault (it's under control panel) to see whether there is an account stored for the reporting server you're connecting to. You could also try to "runAs" visual studio under the proper account name.

Comment: I've tried to run VS as an administrator, without any effect. Also, I've checked Windows Credentials Vault, and there is no stored account.